# Matrix of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is pretty much a check-if-I'm-right sort of question.

Let $φ:K[x]_{\le{n}}\to K[x]_{\le{n-1}}$ with $\varphi$ the linear transformation defind by $\varphi(f)=f'$. Select a base and find the matrix of the linear transformation.

I took the standard basis for grade-$n$ polynomials:

$B =<1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n> ,φ(B)=φ(1,x,x^2,...,x^n) = (0,2x,...,nx^{n-1})$

So, the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\2x\\\dots\\nx^{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: The entris of the matrix are supposed to be elements of $K$.

Comment: Aren't $<1,x^2,...,x^n>$ elements of $K[x]_{\le{n}}$?

Comment: Yes. Is that supposed to be relevant to what I wrote?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $<0,2x,...nx^{n-1}>$.

Comment: Again, is that supposed to be relevant to what I wrote?

Comment: Since they are elements of K, the entries of the matrix are elements of K.

Comment: Wrong: $2x\notin K$.

Comment: Ok, I made a mistake on the post. The base is supposed to be $B=<1,x,x^2...x^n>$.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that $2x,3x^2,\ldots,nx^{n-1}\notin K$.

Comment: Alright then. Any tips on what I should do?

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\varphi(1)=0$, $\varphi(x)=1$, $\varphi(x^2)=2x$, and so on, the matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\0&0&2&0&\ldots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&0&n\end{bmatrix}.$$Note that this matrix has $n(=\dim K[x]_{\leq n-1})$ lines and $n+1(=\dim K[x]_{\leq n})$ columns.

Comment: I don't really understand why it's constructed like this. From the 2nd column forward every pivot of that submatrix is the coefficient of each polynomial bu, I don't get why the first column is like so.

Comment: $\varphi (1)=0$